# Loading datepicker in multiple iterations of an input date field

Tags: javascript, php, forms, input, datepicker

I have a PHP For that loads 5 times the same set of input fields for multiple entries.

At the same time, I have a "datepicker" javascript to be run in the **date** field.

The issue is that only in the first row the datepicker is working. For the next 4 rows loaded, the datepicker doesn't run in the date field.

Code:

```
    <?php 
    for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="includeItem" type="checkbox" onchange="includeMore" name="item<?=$i?>"></td>
        <td><input name="id<?=$i?> style="color:#888;" disabled="disabled"></td>
        <td><input class="formItems" id="datepicker" name="date<?=$i?>"></td>
        <td><input class="formItems" name="description<?=$i?>"></td>
        <td><input class="formItems" name="amount<?=$i?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs should be unique on a page. That means that when you try to select an ID with jQuery it will stop on the first one it finds.

You should use a class to circumvent this, like so.

Code:

```
    <?php 
    for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="includeItem" type="checkbox" onchange="includeMore" name="item<?=$i?>"></td>
        <td><input name="id<?=$i?> style="color:#888;" disabled="disabled"></td>
        <td><input class="formItems" class="datepicker" name="date<?=$i?>"></td>
        <td><input class="formItems" name="description<?=$i?>"></td>
        <td><input class="formItems" name="amount<?=$i?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The same id is not allowed it must be unique - id="datepicker"

Answer (score 1):

Use a class as opposed to an ID.

Give each input a class of "datepicker" and change your jQuery selector to `$(".datepicker")`